# regex pattern to match only strings that don't contain spaces PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to match the word/pattern that is contained in the variable, but only match against the words that don't have white spaces. Please give suggestions.

> $var = 'look';
>
> $array = ('look', 'greatlook',
>   'lookgreat', 'look great', 'badlook',
>   'look bad', 'look    ', '    look');

matches words: look, greatlook, lookgreat, badlook

non matches: look great, bad look, look (trailing space(s)), (space(s)) look.

The syntax of the below functions are OK, but it matches everything

> $match = preg_grep ("/$var/", $array);
>
> $match = preg_grep ("/^$var/",
>   $array); (match words with 'look' at the start)

but when I include the [^\s], it gives an error

$match = preg_grep ("/$var[^\s]/", $array);

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '^', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE

TIA

Comment: be sure to run `$var` through `preg_quote` if there's a chance your words could contain punctuation.

Comment: What about `look greatlook`? Is that a match?

Comment: @ polygenelubricants. No, I don't want to have a space(s) in the matched values

Comment: +1 for asking a regex question with a list of strings you expect to match or reject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
$match = preg_grep("/^\S*$var\S*$/", $array);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this works.


I also removed the \S* at the front of the expression to force matches only with 'look' as the starting characters.  Can you explain what the \ preceding the $ is for? 



I don't searched but I don't see the \ as a requirement for the $ (End of a string).

Comment: @Jamex, actually, it works either way here.  I was worried the `$` would be interpreted as a PHP variable [sigil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: actually, your original solution worked for me,  "/^\S*$var\S*$/".  I just removed the starting part of the expression for another purpose. Sorry for the murky reply, it was late.

Answer (score 1):

The regex would be `^(?=.*look)[^\s]+$`

```
preg_match("/^(?=.*{$var})[^\\s]+$/", $str);

<?
  $str = array('look', 'greatlook', 'lookgreat', 'look great', 'badlook', 'look bad', 'look ', ' look');
  $var = "look";
  $matches = preg_grep("/^(?=.*{$var})[^\\s]+$/", $str);
  print_r ($matches);
?>
//output
Array
(
    [0] => look
    [1] => greatlook
    [2] => lookgreat
    [4] => badlook
)
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not work, the extra \ in the [^\\s] is giving an error, even without the extra slash, the regex is still causing multiple errors, mainly due altering the structure of the $var's pattern.

Comment: @jamex How about `"^(?=.*look)[^\\s]+$"`

Comment: That does not work either, "preg_grep() [function.preg-grep]: Unknown modifier '\' in".  Even if one of the \ is removed, it is still showing the same error.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, sorry that I did not catch the error. I am not familiar with the syntax, and it was late.

Answer (score -1):

```
$match = preg_grep ("/{$var}[^\s]/", $array);
```

I believe that you need to enclose the variable in curly brackets because the characters continue on without whitespace.

Comment: That means the next character isn't whitespace.  "looka " still matches.  Also, words ending in $var (including look) don't, because there is no next character.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not work, the curly brackets alter the pattern.